# How to Create a JSON_OBJECT in MySql From Rows of Key-Value Data

Tags: mysql, sql, json, aggregate-functions

In MySQL, I am trying to create a JSON_OBJECT from rows of data containing key-value pairs.

Here is the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TempValuePair( MyKey VARCHAR(64), MyValue VARCHAR(64) );
INSERT INTO TempValuePair VALUE 
    ('Country', 'Argentina'), 
    ('Capital', 'Buenos Aires'), 
    ('Population', 45810000 );
```

The following statement seems to return an argument that conforms to the JSON_OBJECT requirements:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 
    CONCAT( '\'', MyKey, '\',\'', Myvalue, '\'' ) 
    ORDER BY MyKey 
) 
FROM TempValuePair;
```

However, the following statement fails:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 
        CONCAT( '\'', MyKey, '\',\'', Myvalue, '\'' ) 
        ORDER BY MyKey 
    ) 
    FROM TempValuePair 
);
```

Any advice about what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *seem* to want [`json_objectagg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg), which is available in MySQL since version 5.7. The function aggregates key/value pairs from multiple rows into a single JSON object:

```
select json_objectagg(mykey, myvalue) as js from TempValuePair;
```

Yields:

```
{"Capital": "Buenos Aires", "Country": "Argentina", "Population": "45810000"}
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u6r42kvu)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed to learn - thank you very much for your help !